# Multiple Google Charts inside JQuery Cycle

Tags: javascript, api, charts, slider

I am trying to create a cycle/slider that has two google charts in it.  I can display them separately on the page with the below code, but when space became premium I decided to go to slider/cycle.  With the below code.  The first chart draws but when the second scrolls into view.  There is no chart.  It only says: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference on Chrome: Cannot read property 'length' of null.  I realize that when one chart is visible the other is not.  But my unfamiliarity with javascript is making it hard to come up with an answer that will turn display:'block' to display:'none at the appropriate times and back.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function drawCharts() {
            var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<% =jsostring%>);
            var options1 = {
                title: 'PSNL Weight Chart',
                backgroundColor: {fill:'none'}
            };

            var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<% =jsostring2%>);
            var options2 = {
                title: 'PSNL Sleep Chart',
                backgroundColor: {fill:'none'}
            };

            var chartA = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chartA.draw(data1, options1);

            var chartB = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
            chartB.draw(data2, options2);

        }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });

       </script>
```

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is very basic.  I'm not a java person.  I searched and thought about it.  The answer, which I found on another site is:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function drawCharts() {
            var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<% = jsostring%>);
            var options1 = {
                title: 'PSNL Weight Chart',
                backgroundColor: {fill:'none'}
            };

            var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<% = jsostring2%>);
            var options2 = {
                title: 'PSNL Sleep Chart',
                backgroundColor: {fill:'none'}
            };

            var chartA = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            document.getElementById('chart_div').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('chart_div2').style.display = 'none';
            chartA.draw(data1, options1);

            var chartB = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
            document.getElementById('chart_div2').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('chart_div').style.display = 'none';
            chartB.draw(data2, options2);
        }
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);
        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });

</script>
```

As the jquery scroll through.  It will turn on the first Div_Chart and turn off the other before it scrolls into view.